# Navigation in increased image (translating x,y) wp7

Tags: c#, silverlight, image, windows-phone-7

I want to navigate in increased image, but my code doesn't work. What I have so far:

```
 private void StartMoving(object sender, Microsoft.Phone.Controls.GestureEventArgs e) 
 {
     var finger1 = e.GetPosition(MainImage);
     var transform = (CompositeTransform)MainImage.RenderTransform;
     transform.Transform(finger1);
 }
```

XAML:

```
 <Image Name="MainImage">
     <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
         <toolkit:GestureListener DoubleTap="OnDoubleTap" Flick="OnFlick"
                                  GestureBegin="StartMoving"
                                  PinchStarted="OnPinchStarted"
                                  PinchDelta="OnPinchDelta"/>
     </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
     <Image.RenderTransform>
         <CompositeTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" TranslateX="0" TranslateY="0"/>
     </Image.RenderTransform>
 </Image>
```

I need something like this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FOk8m0MG6Lw

How can I make this work?

Comment: It is not clear from your description what you are specifically having trouble with.

Comment: I need to develop moving gesture in increased picture, like in a video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   MainImage.ManipulationDelta += PhoneApplicationPage_ManipulationDelta;
        }...
        void PhoneApplicationPage_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e) {
          // Scale the rectangle.
          // Move the rectangle.
          var transform = (CompositeTransform)MainImage.RenderTransform;
          if (transform.ScaleX != 1 || transform.ScaleY != 1) {
            transform.TranslateX += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X;
            transform.TranslateY += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y;
          }
        }
```